# NoSuchMethodError after including two libraries using ProGuard

Tags: android, gradle, android-proguard

I'm trying to include two libraries ([panframe](http://www.panframe.com/) and [indoo.rs](http://indoo.rs)) into my Android project using Gradle 2.1.2. Both were using ProGuard presumably to obfuscate their private methods. Since both libs use the same obfuscation pattern, a call to a static method from the indoo.rs worker service in onBind() leads to an ambiguity for the ClassLoader:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method a(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; in class Lcom/a/a/a/g; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.a.a.a.g' appears in /data/data/com.companytest/files/instant-run/dex/slice-panframe-1.9_e8c65b231b25083f170d9dc622b9f9f514e9ecef-classes.dex)
>                                                                                  at com.a.a.h.a.j$a.(SourceFile:449)
>                                                                                  at com.a.a.h.a.j.a(SourceFile:411)
>                                                                                  at com.customlbs.service.Worker.onBind(SourceFile:184)
>                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindService(ActivityThread.java:3834)
>                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:221)
>                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1887)
>                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
>                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7225)
>                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
>                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)

Apart from not obfuscating com.a.a.h.a.j.a in the indoo.rs library, is there any method to prevent this?

Comment: You need to get the proguard rules for both of the libraries so proguard will know what to keep.